# A quick question on Expectation and Variance

Tags: probability, expectation, binomial-distribution, variance

Question:

> 1. For a particular flight, there are 100 seats available and 103 tickets have been sold
> 2. the probability that a passenger may not show up, is $p$. (where $0 < p < 1$ )
>
> What is the variance of the number of people who show up for the
>   flight?

From my understanding,

$Var(x) = E[x^2] - (E[x])^2$


$ x$ ~ $Binomial(n, 1-p)$, 

=> $E[x] = n*p = 103(1-p)$

But for $E[x^2]$, 

for $x^2$ is that also a binomial distribution like $x$? (I get stucked here)

How could we calculate $E[x^2]$ in this case?

Many thanks!

Comment: actually $X \sim Bin(n, 1-p)$ for this particular question. The intermediate step for expectation is wrong but the final answer for expectation is right.

Answer (score 0):

First of all $$\mathrm{Var} X = \mathbb{E}\left[X^2\right] - \mathbb{E}[X]^2.$$

As you noted correctly,
$$
\mathbb{E}[X] = np = 103(1-p)
$$
Now, for each of the passengers $x_i$ you get a Bernoulli distribution with 1 as success as 0 as a failure, and
$$
\mathbb{E}[x_i^2] = 1^2p + 0^2(1-p)=p
$$
so
$$
\mathrm{Var} x_i
 = \mathbb{E}\left[x_i^2\right] - \mathbb{E}[x]^2
 = p - p^2 = p(1-p).
$$

In our case, we have $X = \sum_{i=1}^n x_i$ which are independent and identically distributed random variables, so
$$
\mathrm{Var} X = \sum_{i=1}^n \mathrm{Var\ } x_i
 = \sum_{i=1}^n p(1-p) = np(1-p).
$$

The alternative way is to remember that your random variable $X$ can take on values $0, 1, \ldots, n =103$ with probability $$p_k = \binom{n}{k} p^k (1-p)^{n-k},$$ so just like
$$
\mathbb{E}[X]
 = \sum_{k=0}^n k \cdot p_k
 = \sum_{k=0}^n k \cdot \binom{n}{k} p^k (1-p)^{n-k}
$$
we also have (using the Law of the Unconscious Statistician)
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[X^2\right]
 = \sum_{k=0}^n k^2 \cdot p_k
 = \sum_{k=0}^n k^2 \cdot \binom{n}{k} p^k (1-p)^{n-k}
$$
To compute something like that analytically you note that
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n k^2 \cdot \binom{n}{k} p^k (1-p)^{n-k}
= (1-p)^n \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} k^2 \left(\frac{p}{1-p}\right)^k
$$
which can be obtained by manipulating the second derivative of
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} z^k
$$
and let $z = p/(1-p)$.